# Flutter web-custom url scheme?

Tags: flutter, server, flutter-web, reroute

Recently, Flutter added support for custom schemes in urls, meaning we can remove the hashtag in the url scheme. This works fine and dandy and launches all screens without the hashtag url. However, if we manually try to go to the direct page, such as page.com/homepage, a 404 error comes up (if we wanted to go to page.com/#/homepage). Note: this error does not come up when running on the flutter web-server, it only comes up after publishing it online. How do we redirect all pages to index.html to launch that specific screen?

Comment: Just curious where did you read this `Flutter added support for custom schemes in urls, meaning we can remove the hashtag in the url scheme.`?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33245